# How to return multiple values in a subquery TSQL

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

So this may be a simple solution but I can't seem to figure out how to get this procedure to work.

ALTER proc FAQs_SelectById
@Id int

as

BEGIN

```
SELECT faqi.[Id]
        ,faqi.[FAQId]
        ,faq.[Name]
        ,TotalInstances = (Select count(Id) from FAQInstances)
        ,QuestionCount = (Select count(Id) from FAQQuestions 
                          )
        ,faqa.Answer
        ,faqi.[DateCreated]
        ,faqi.[DateModified]

FROM [FAQInstances] AS faqi
INNER JOIN [FAQs] AS faq ON faqi.FAQId = faq.Id
inner join FAQQuestions as faqq on faqq.FAQId = faq.Id
inner join FAQAnswers as faqa on faqa.QuestionId = faqq.Id

WHERE faq.Id = @Id
```

END

So this statement gives me what I need: `Select count(Id) from FAQInstances group by FAQId`
I have tried inserting that into my subquery but get "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression" error

I have tried putting into the subquery:

```
Select TotalInstances = (Select count(Id) from FAQInstances Where faq.Id = faqi.FAQId)
```

But this just gives me the total across all FAQ.Id's

I have done my own research but the advice can't be applied to my use case (at least I don't think so)

I would appreciate explanations alongside your advice to help me learn.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Rather than telling us that your code and data are above our pay grade, create an example with generic terms and data that replicates the issue and don't mention that you deal in <redacted> level security. You may get some insights from [Correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver16#correlated) and [Correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This subquery: `Select count(Id) from table1 group by ItemId`
returns multiple rows. One per ItemId, as the `group by` commands.

Very much like the error says to you, if you put the query inside parentheses after an equals sign, it's like you *promise* sql server that your query returns only one row with one column.

But yours does not. Yours returns one row per ItemID. This is more than one row.

So the question is: What are you really trying to do with `TotalPerItemId`? Is it just an alias of the column? That would be `Select TotalPerItemId=count(Id) from table1 group by ItemId`. Do you want to do a double aggregation, like finding the maximum among all counts? It is not clear from your question.

------------------------- POST COMMENT EDIT

Disclaimer: Either your schema or your query is a little strange. Keep in mind that if for some [FAQs].[Id] there are 2 [FAQInstances], 3 [FAQQuestions] and 4 [FAQAnswers], your query will return 2*3*4=24 rows.
Also: you have a columnd named [FAQId], which is coming from [FAQInstances], but not any respective column from [FAQQuestions]; suspiciously asymmetric.

I highly recommend you *avoid* using subqueries before the `FROM` part of your query. It expects only one value, and causes confusion.

Here is a solution using one query:

```
SELECT 
     faqi.[Id]
    ,faqi.[FAQId]
    ,faq.[Name]
    ,TotalInstances = count_inst.TotalInstances
    ,QuestionCount = count_quest.FAQQuestions
    ,faqa.Answer
    ,faqi.[DateCreated]
    ,faqi.[DateModified]
FROM 
    [FAQInstances] AS faqi
    INNER JOIN [FAQs] AS faq ON faqi.FAQId = faq.Id
    inner join FAQQuestions as faqq on faqq.FAQId = faq.Id
    inner join FAQAnswers as faqa on faqa.QuestionId = faqq.Id
    cross apply
    (
        select TotalInstances=count(*)
        from FAQInstances faqic
        where faqic.FAQId=faq.Id
    ) as count_inst
    cross apply
    (
        select QuestionCount=count(*)
        from FAQQuestions faqqu
        where faqqu.FAQId=faq.Id
    ) as count_quest
WHERE faq.Id = @Id
```

Comment: Maybe I chose a bad example, Let's say I have a FAQ with 3 Id's (FAQ Topics). Each Id has multiple questions and each question has multiple answers, I want to get the total of questions and answers per each question per FAQ Id. I'll edit my post to better explain once I have some time

Comment: Oh wow! So much I have to learn. I've only really done joins and subqueries so far. I'll try this out.

Comment: If you could indulge, are there any useful things like cross apply I should research on?

Comment: There are many things to learn, always, and it's not easy to make a list. Search, search, search, learn, learn, learn...